# Moving a matrix (array) to the left margin

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, arrays

So, of particular interest to my question is the second to last line of the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum} %a garbage package you don't need except to create examples.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[
    top    = 2.00cm,
    bottom = 2.10cm,
    left   = 1.70cm,
    right  = 1.70cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

%newline cmd
\newcommand{\newl}{\\ \text{} \\}
%end newline cmd

%right align page numbers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{1.2-3 | Gaussian elimination, arithmetic of matrices, and matrix operations}
\rhead{Mackey \thepage}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%end right align page numbers

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\hphantom{\hspace{6.33258819580078124999999... in}}
$$

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[... is a repeating sequence of 9's]

I am looking to shift this matrix to the left of the page, without having to trial for the proper number of digits/values. I should certainly hope that there is some means of doing this, one more simpler than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is only an isolated array, a simple way is

```
\noindent
$\displaystyle
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$
```

This works because the array is at the beginning of a paragraph and this paragraph indentation is set to 0pt.

Answer (score 6):

Two ways, both disallowing a page break before the matrix:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for some text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\makebox[\displaywidth][l]{$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$}
\]
\lipsum*[2]\\*[\abovedisplayskip]
$\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$\\[\belowdisplayskip]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions: one playing with TeX math lengths, one with the `flalign*` environment from `amsmath`. Incidentall, I simplified you matrix code using the `bmatrix*` environment from `mathtools` (which loads amsmath):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\[ \displayindent = -0.5\textwidth
  \mathrlap{\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix*} }
\]%

\begin{flalign*}
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix*} & & &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]